# Google Earth KML - Weird GE behavior when using balloon links to fragment URLs when doc loaded via NetworkLink

Tags: kml, google-earth

KML newb here. First post.

Using GE client application, v7.12. Have fairly simple KML doc containing placemarks to several GPS time-based breadcrumb points.  Wrote a simple C# app to generate the kml doc. Expect to have several more like files for additional tracked entities.  I get this working and decide to fancy up the placemark balloons via HTML. Ultimately decide I'd like to have links in the balloon to move to the previous or next placemark. Find advice on this site and make it happen.

Since my app may update(by rewriting) the doc at times it would be nice to not have to manually reload it.  Plus there will ultimately be other docs for other tracked entities, all controlled/updated by my app.  OK - NetworkLink to the rescue.  Cool feature and gives me the option of dynamically modifying the networklinks file to only include the entity doc files that have changed.  Plus big bonus -- turning 'flyToView' off so that when networklinks file is reloaded or refresh fires, I'm not pulled away from whatever I'm currently viewing by the default 'LookAt' that normally seems to happen when a doc is loaded directly (anyone know a way around this?)

Very happy, until I discover that when I click one of my balloon links to move to the next or previous point, GE decides to create a new copy of the entire containing document under Temporary Places and now I have two entire sets of points displayed, one hiding the other.  On the surface, my next/prev links appear to be working, but they are actually only working with the newly created doc. To test, I alter the original doc with an entirely different set of locations.  Reload the networklinks doc to bring in the new point-laden doc and see the new set of points.  But when I use any balloon links on the new, they jump to points on the older doc that GE had created on its own.  Delete the GE-created version, click balloon and viola, GE creates a new copy of it and were back where we started.  Frustrating.

As placemark IDs, I'm using strings like "TPn", where n increments.  In my balloon links, I'm linking to the fragment URLs such as href="#TPn-1" and href="TPn+1", ie TP2 links to TP1 and TP3, etc, and I account for both placemarks on the end so they don't have bad links to non-existent IDs.  BTW, I've found when you do activate a link to a non-existent fragment URL, GE also decides to create a copy of the file, even if the file was loaded directly and not via a networklink, so you again have one point set laying on top of the other.  However, I'm confident I have no bad links in this case.

Any light that can be shed would be appreciated.  Or alternate ways of achieving my goals.  I'm a KML newb after all and maybe there's something I'm doing wrong.

I suppose if I have to, I will sacrifice the balloon links.  Being able to reload only one networklinks document for a collection of files + timed refresh + turning off flyToView are too desirable to lose now.

Thanks!

EDIT: Additional info - The duplicate document is created only when using balloon links.  Clicking a link in the treeview under the placemark does not cause this anomaly.  (In the code sample, remove the null Snippet element for each Placemark to see this effect.)  Furthermore, it appears that a balloon link to **ANY** fragment URL causes the anomaly, such as a link back to a containing folder or document.

EDIT: Added 2 code samples.  These are pared down to my essential needs, but still demonstrate the problem.  Interesting to note the difference in the GE tree view when the data file 'document' element has an 'id' defined vs not, but it has no bearing on the problem.  I prefer the look when the id is omitted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

<!-- File is: C:\myTwoDataPoints.kml -->

<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="myDoc">
    <name>Two Points Doc Name Here</name>
    <description>Doc Description Here</description>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <Snippet>Contains Two Data Points</Snippet>

    <Style id="myStyle">
      <BalloonStyle >
        <text><![CDATA[Link To:&nbsp;$[description] ]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>

    <Folder>
      <name>Points Folder</name>
      <open>1</open>

      <Placemark id="TP1">
        <name>Miami, FL, USA</name>
        <Snippet />
        <description><![CDATA[<a href="#TP2;balloonFlyto">New York</a>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#myStyle</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-80.226439,25.788969,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>

      <Placemark id="TP2">
        <name>New York, NY, USA</name>
        <Snippet />
        <description><![CDATA[<a href="#TP1;balloonFlyto">Miami</a>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#myStyle</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-74.005973,40.714353,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>

      </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

and...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- File is: C:\myNetworkLink.kml -->

<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>NetworkLink Document Name Here</name>
  <visibility>0</visibility>
  <open>1</open>

  <NetworkLink>
    <name>NetworkLink Name Here</name>
    <refreshVisibility>1</refreshVisibility>
    <flyToView>0</flyToView>
    <Link><href>file:///C:/myTwoDataPoints.kml</href></Link>
  </NetworkLink>

</Document>
</kml>
```